# Tar archive header not storing size of directory?

Tags: go

How does `tar -cf` store information about the size of a directory that it archives? I'm able to read headers for actual **files** but when I come across a header that represents metadata for a **directory**, I'm seeing that the size of the directory is 0...

Perhaps I am just streaming the tar archive incorrectly? However, I don't see how likely that is since I am able to get information from regular files fine.

Comment: This is expected behaviour; `tar`ed directories don't have sizes.

Comment: @steve The directories in your filesystem have a size, but I don't think it's what you expect; it's only the size of the all the file entries, not the size of the files. In a tar file they don't contain a directory listing, and have no size.

Comment: @JimB playing around on a shell, there is some notion of space that the directory takes up, usually it is 4096 Bytes on Linux machines. Can a tar not know this kind of information?

Comment: @steve: that's irrelevant to tar, because that space is taken up by filesystem specific data to store the directory contents. Conceptually directories take no space at all, and that is how tar represents them.